# table empty in report viewer c#

Tags: c#

here is my load function:[there is no data visbile in the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuwIL.png)

```
DataSet1 ds = new DataSet1();
reportViewer1.Visible = true;
reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "ReportingInDotNet.WinformsDotNet6.LibrarianReport.rdlc";
reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "C:\\Users\\abd elrahman\\Downloads\\DatabaseProject11.0\\DatabaseProject\\LibrarianReport.rdlc";
ReportDataSource dataSource = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", ds.Tables[0]);
reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(dataSource);
reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

i was expecting data to appear in the table

Comment: Which data were you expecting ? You never seem to select anything from the database.

Comment: what is this `reportViewer1` thing? is this microsoft access? if yes, please add [tag:ms-access] tag.

Comment: @BagusTesa: [Use the WinForms ReportViewer Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/application-integration/using-the-winforms-reportviewer-control?view=sql-server-ver16) ?  OR [Microsoft RDLC Report Designer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftRdlcReportDesignerforVisualStudio-18001)

Comment: @Luuk either winform or webform. there are at least two different `ReportViewer` classes. not to mention the thing in ms access (cant remember the name, but they look similar).